# Sending Google Tag Custom Events as a batch

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I can send a custom event with the following code to GA4:

```
window.gtag('event', 'offer_view', { 'offer_id': offer_id });
```

I can then use google analytics data api to get the event counts for each offer ID.

```
{
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "2023-04-01"
      "endDate": "2023-05-01"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "eventCount"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "customEvent:offer_id"
    }
  ],
  "dimensionFilter": {
    "filter": {
      "fieldName": "customEvent:offer_id",
      "inListFilter": {
        "values": [
          "75",
          "76",
          "37"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good...

This is used to track the impressions of a product on an e-commerce website. As the user can view dozens if not hundreds of products, this will fire too many requests from the client side, which is not desirable.

Is there a way to batch these same events and send all the offer_id's in one request?

I tried to send an array but the offer_id is displayed as array as expected. I would be grateful for your guidance/pointers.

Thanks

Comment: There's no need to batch it on your side. Gtag will batch them for you. Send multiple offer_view events rapidly and look at your network tab. See how it will only send one request. Gtag normally has a delay before sending a request. There are conditions that remove the delay, but they're mostly for debugging.

Comment: Many thanks, I would accepted it as an answer if you post it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting the comment as an answer:

There's no need to batch it on your side. Gtag will batch them for you. Send multiple offer_view events rapidly and look at your network tab. See how it will only send one request. Gtag normally has a delay before sending a request. There are conditions that remove the delay, but they're mostly for debugging. You can read more about batching mechanics at the end of this page: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en